# Call Twig function from another Twig function

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a path that needs alot of arguments:

```
{{ path('work_path', {'username': work.user.username, 'work_id': work.id, 'work_slug': work.slug}) }}
```

Instead of using this long line everywhere I want to have a specific function for this path only.

Is there a way to call the `path()` function from my custom function (besides passing the *Router* service to the extension class)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of possible solutions, you might be interested in writing your own [twig macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html).

Comment: I don't really like macros because you have to import them everywhere :/

Comment: @tamir then, passing twig as service to your extension seems to be the only solution, if you don't like to include macro